# Tightest upper bound for worst case of comparison based sorting?

Tags: sorting, complexity-theory

Is there a way of showing the tightest upper bound for the worst case of comparison based sorting? Isn't it completely implementation dependent?  I could very well design a code that will compare every element of the array with every other element..it will be inefficient but it will not be wrong.

So like the tightest lower bound for the worst case (which is Ω(n log n)) is there any tightest upper bound too?

Answer (score 0):

No the lower bound for worst case comparison based sorting is `O(n log n)`.
See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) for a short proof.
Or theorem 8.1 in [Introduction to Algorithms](http://books.google.nl/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=introduction%20to%20algorithms%20proof%20upperbound%20worst%20case%20sorting&source=bl&ots=BxWoAz3nB9&sig=34MKIiDrt7WaL5LpZoXKId_Y8nE&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=1HX4Uo7bCIOY0AWDuYDQCw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20algorithms%20proof%20upperbound%20worst%20case%20sorting&f=false) (click next in the top).

Wait I misread your question. You cannot have a tightest upper bound, since you can always make your algorithm more complex, however you can prove that for every comparison based sorting algorithm there exists a worst case scenario that takes at least `O(n log n)` (and often at most) comparisons to be sorted.